# Android Studio - image button is crashing after i click on it

Tags: java, android, button, crash

I am trying to make some simple image click button to go to another activity but I can't get it to work.

It says:

```
Unfortunately, myapp has stopped.
```

If I highlighted my android: `onClick="myButton"` it says `Method myButton' is missing in 'MainActivity' in my layout.xml`

MainActivity.java

```
package com.zemoapps.alarmclockgold;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Typeface;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;


//Old code "public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {"
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private Button myButton;


    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);



        TextView myTextview = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.RepeatingText);
        TextView myTextview2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.CountDownText);
        Typeface myCustomFont = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "fonts/AndadaRegular.otf");
        myTextview.setTypeface(myCustomFont);
        myTextview2.setTypeface(myCustomFont);


    }

    public class MyCustomTextView extends TextView {

        public MyCustomTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
            super(context, attrs);
            this.setTypeface(Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(),
                    "fonts/AndadaRegular.otf"));
        }

    }

    public class AlarmPage extends AppCompatActivity {

        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

            myButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.RepeatingImage);

            myButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {

                    startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, AddAlarm.class));

                }
            });


        }


    }}
```

Layout.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:andriod="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/BG"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="#9e84d3"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="com.zemoapps.onething.MainActivity">

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/RepeatingImage"
    android:layout_width="200dp"
    android:layout_height="150dp"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:background="#00000000"
    android:contentDescription="@null"
    android:onClick="myButton"
    android:scaleType="fitCenter"
    android:src="@drawable/alarm1" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

`AndroidManifest` says there is error too:
[image]

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not find method myButton(View) in a parent or ancestor Context for android:onClick attribute defined on view class android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageButton with id 'RepeatingImage'
                                                                                 at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.resolveMethod(AppCompatViewInflater.java:307)
                                                                                 at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:266)
                                                                                 at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4084)
                                                                                 at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:16966)
                                                                                 at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
                                                                                 at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
                                                                                 at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
                                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
                                                                                 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                                                                                 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
                                                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
                                                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
                                                                                 at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: ImageButton myButton = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.RepeatingImage);

Comment: Why is the Alarm Activity content View **the same** as the Main Activity one? As in `setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);`

Answer (score 1):

Remove android:onClick="myButton" from ImageButton in your XML.

```
<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/RepeatingImage"
    android:layout_width="200dp"
    android:layout_height="150dp"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:background="#00000000"
    android:contentDescription="@null"
    android:onClick="myButton" // remove this line from your xml
    android:scaleType="fitCenter"
    android:src="@drawable/alarm1" />
```

Comment: But then how can i make my button clickable?

Comment: In your Activity class you are already adding listener on it:                            myButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.RepeatingImage);

            myButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {...}

Answer (score 1):

This is  because you have extended AppCompatActivity.
It will work fine if you extend Activity.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't define method for imagebutton click,you should add it to `MainActivity` like this:

```
public void myButton(View view){
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the next row from you ImageButton node:

```
android:onClick="myButton"
```

When you add it, Android will expect a method named "myButton" in your Activity.